# Is $C(X)$ dense in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $X$ be locally compact Hausdorff.

Let $\mu$ be a complete measure on $X$.

Is $C(X)$ dense in $L^p(\mu)$?

Comment: If $p < \infty$, yes: The citation is Theorem 3.14 in green Rudin.

Comment: @T.Bongers What do you mean green Rudin? RCA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, for $p < \infty$, provided some conditions on the measure $\mu$ (regularity, finiteness of measure for compact sets, etc.; these are the conclusions from Theorem $2.14$), and I'm assuming that you mean $C_c(X)$: note that if $\mu$ is not a finite measure, $C(X)$ isn't even contained in $L^p$: Consider a constant function.

From Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis* Theorem $3.14$ (page $69$ in my edition), this can be proved immediately by combining Lusin's theorem (that every $L^p$ function can be approximated in norm by a continuous function with compact support) together with the density of simple functions with finite support.

The assertion is quite false for $p = \infty$.

Comment: Do you think an assertion "Stone-Weierstrass Theorem implies $C(X)$ is dense in $L^p$" makes sense? My professor told me SWT imples this, but i hardly believe..

Comment: That theorem is about $C_c(X)$, not $C(X)$. There are also some additional assumptions on $\mu$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Right, I forgot to include my assumptions. Thanks.

Comment: @T.Bongers Since Rudin does not go deep into measure theory and just provide a measure by using Riesz representation, i feel like he is restricting contents in this case. Is finiteness of measure for compact sets really necessary?

Comment: @user140374 I'd have to think about it some more, but I'd guess that something at least that strong is necessary to prove Lusin's theorem.

Answer (score 3):

$C(X)$ is not even contained in $L^p(\mu)$ if $\mu$ is an infinite measure.
There are cases where $L^p(\mu)$ contains no nontrivial continuous functions, 
e.g. counting measure on the rational numbers (with $X = \mathbb R$).

Comment: The rationals are not locally compact, though.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $X = \mathbb R$.